# NJS-116: password verifier type 0x939 is not supported by node-oracledb in Thin mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to connect Oracle db with node.js using javaScript.

requirement -I am automating UI using webdriverIo which uses node.js and JS .In one flow I need to connect with oracle DB and get the value by running the query through automation.
I tried everything but every time same response.
I am trying to connect oracle db ,using Nodejs and JS  .I am using VScode for coding.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle Database 11gR2 or earlier:

- Add a call to `initOracleClient()` to enable node-oracledb [Thick mode](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-node-oracledb-thick-mode)
- Alternatively you could upgrade the database.

For Oracle Database 12c or later:

- To use Thin mode: see the Oracle documentation on [Finding and Resetting User Passwords That Use the 10G Password Version](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-D7B09DFE-F55D-449A-8F8A-174D89936304).  In summary:

  1. Make sure the database initialization parameter `sec_case_sensitive_logon` is not FALSE.  In SQL*Plus as SYSDBA, run `show parameter sec_case_sensitive_logon` to check the value.
     (Note `sec_case_sensitive_logon` has been [removed in DB 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/security-solutions.html#GUID-FAF4C7A6-A2CD-4B9B-9A64-3705F693ECF0)).
  2. If the error still occurs, regenerate passwords e.g. run `ALTER USER x IDENTIFIED BY y`, if necessary.
- Alternatively you could use Thick mode.

Comment: I dont have access to update sec_case_sensitive_logon is not FALSE. I tried calling  above Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary for Node.js. Please try using Thin mode.

Comment: I tried calling  initOracleClient() ,received below error.                                                                Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb Thick mode binary for Node.js. Please try using Thin mode.

Comment: Read the [node-oracledb installation doc](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).  Open a new issue if you further questions.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem and after some time researching it I found out that here's some problem running typeorm@^0.3.17 and oracledb@^6.0.3 together on MacOS with M1 onboard. Also the problem is that typeorm uses an old version of oracledb package (^5.1.0). Hope that developers would update the version soon, PR is ready here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/10285
I think after it will be merged the issue could be fixed

UPD:
If you, like me, are using Mac on M1 processor try this guide

https://medium.com/oracledevs/how-to-install-node-oracledb-5-5-and-oracle-database-on-apple-m1-m2-silicon-941fccda692f

it could help

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1584. Your user credentials are assigned to a less secure 10G password verifier.

Node-oracledb's Thin mode (v6.0.0 and higher) supports 11G and higher password verifiers, which are more secure.
To reset your password verifier to use more secure versions in your Oracle Database, please follow the steps listed here - R[esetting Oracle Database password verifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spuss/finding-and-resetting-user-passwords-10g-password-version.html#GUID-D7B09DFE-F55D-449A-8F8A-174D89936304).